# What is This XML Object Used in the Client Side Hashing Method of My Router's Config Page?

Tags: hash, python-requests, http-headers, sha256

```
payload = {
    'Username': 'admin',
    'Password': 'e451cc1e5885cae5bec2640cf40c7ee6cc09010ddc6f897963641fa63d6852be',
    'action': 'login',
    '_sessionTOKEN': '510252081095712727960760'
}
```

This is the payload sent with my POST request when I try to login my router's configuration page (which is at http://192.168.1.1) with the credentials "admin" for username and "1" for the password. So obviously password gets hashed with sha256 (hash analyzers on internet told so) but  sha256("1") doesn't match the 'Password' token above. Later on I inspected the source HTML and found this method between `<script></script>` tags:

```js
function g_loginToken(xml) {
    var xmlObj = $(xml).text();
    var Password = $("#Frm_Password").val();
    var SHA256Password = sha256(Password + xmlObj);
    var LoginFormObj = new webSubmitForm();
    LoginFormObj.addParameter("Username", $("#Frm_Username").val());
    LoginFormObj.addParameter("Password", SHA256Password);
    LoginFormObj.addParameter("action", "login");
    LoginFormObj.addParameter("_sessionTOKEN", "313949915505130291199244");
    LoginFormObj.Form.submit();
    Password = undefined;
    SHA256Password = undefined;
}
```

If i'm not mistaken the password I provide (which is "1" in this particular case) gets concatenated with some XML object which is passed as a parameter to the g_loginToken function. I don't know what would the XML object be, perhaps I'd predict like my request headers serialized as XML, further than that I have no idea. Help is appreciated.

Edit: Here is how the "xml" and "xmlObj" variables look like after setting a breakpoint where they get defined, by the advice from @AndrejKesely
I still don't know what these values represent though.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe is useful to try web developer tools (in Chrome or Firefox) and set breakpoint inside this function and inspect what `xml` contains.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I lack the knowledge and experience to perform that and interpret the content I get but I definitely will give a try, thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Obtained from here `http://{router_ip}/function_module/login_module/login_page/logintoken_lua.lua?_={unix_time}` at least on my router.
  I tested without passing unix time in the request and it generated a token which didn't work.
- It is used for salting which renders rainbow tables useless, also prevents replay attacks because the salt/token will change on the next request for login.
- For your specific router you can run wireshark to find the information needed.
- To calculate the salted sha256 you have to do sha256(password+login_token)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Same URL leads to same file for my router as well, I think it's the same model with yours. When I checked the Wireshark, I saw a request is being made to that URL before the POST req is done. So is it safe to assume that token being sent is simply sha256("pass" + "{unixtime}") ?